# addressing multicollinearity and low levels in PCA

Tags: pca

I am trying to build a multiple regression model to predict properties prices and I would like to cunduct PCA to choose the most relevant variables.

1. I know that the the variables should be uncorrelated. What would be the best way to check and deal with multicollinearity? I have 80 variables. I have tried correlation plot and VIF function in r and deleted those ones with VIF around 10 (>=9.9 should I be more/less conservative??).
2. After I created dummy variables out of my categorical variables I applied
   prin_comp <- prcomp(pca.train, scale. = T) and then it returned an error: Error in prcomp.default(pca.train, scale. = T) : 
   cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance.
   I do realize that some of the levels whithin the factors(there are about 17 of them with such a condition) don´t appear very often in the dataset and as a dummy variable contain mostly zeros. What can I do about such an unfair level distribution?

I am new to stats so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you genuinely care about prediction and not at all about explanation (cause and effect), then with a large enough sample size you needn't exclude any of your predictors, even the very collinear ones.  If your sample size is on the small side, e.g., < 1600, then you have a considerable number of choices to make in reducing from 80 predictors.  You could continue to judge based on VIF or you could look up variable selection or regularization methods.
2. You probably have variables that have no variation when the data set is reduced to just those cases missing no data (the complete cases).  Eliminating these variables should help; or you could embark on imputation of missing values.

EDIT:  Since from your comments you are reluctant to exclude predictors, and since apparently missing data are not much of an issue, you could, for predictive purposes, conduct PCA on the majority of variables, while keeping others intact outside of the PCA, e.g., preserving all categories.  Levels (dummy variables) with nearly all zeroes will prove relatively uninformative; I wouldn't expect much predictive power to come from a category with 3 "1"s out of 2500 cases.  But at least you wouldn't be ruling anything out as a *possible* predictor.

As to a subjective rating of quality, there's nothing wrong with adding that if you feel it will be valid and reliable.  If it's collinear with other predictors,  you won't have lost anything by trying it.

More problematic is your statement that you want to "explain what influences the property price."  For this you would have the unenviable task of reducing your 80 predictors to a subset that covers the different domains you and other experts might have identified (location, style, various aspects of quality, etc.) while also avoiding the inflation of coefficient standard errors that comes with correlated predictors.  Ideally this would be a collaborative task for which you would allow plenty of time and multiple iterations of analysis.

Comment: Thank you ronaldo! 1.The idea is to explain what influences the property price in the first place and then create a model that predicts the price. There are about 2500 rows in my dataset. That´s why I thought PCA or Boruta would help to select the most important variables to include in my model.

Comment: 2. I have already used nearZeroVar() function to eliminate no variation variables. But the thing is that I have many categorical variables and 17 of them have many levels (10-20) and some of them rarely occur. For example in the neighbourhood variable there 20 levels and let´s say there are a couple of neghbourhoods that only appear 2-3 times. Any idea what I can do with them? Is there any threashold of the number of cases whithin a level? I really don´t want to just drop the data.

Comment: 3. It might be a silly question, but I was wondering if it is at all possible to set a categorical variable of quality, like overall quality (and I have kitchen, basement, etc quality) as numeric variable? Let´s say very poor -1 , excellent -10. And then later check them colliniarity? I feel like they might be correlated.

Comment: I tried PCA and Boruta. Apparently my big poblem is low level categorical variables(there are 32 of them out of 82). For now I am recoding those levels < 5% to "Others".  Using my data without modifications in PCA after creating dummy variables  returns 150 significant varibles. I want to find the way to reduce 80 variables of my dataset to aprox. 20 the most important ones to later on create  a regression model to predict the price.

Comment: Hi Ronaldo! I am now at the stage of numerical variables transformation. I have read about standardization and various transformations like log, etc., which made me feel very confused. My numerical variables are square meters, age (in years), and number of attributes like bathrooms, rooms (they are approx. between 1-5). My questions are:

1.The area and price variables distributions are kind of right-skewed. Would it be ok if I log transform all of them?

Comment: 2. The age variables distributions are multimodal. Are there any transformations that I can apply in this case? Should I leave them as they are or just discard them from the modeling?

3. How should I treat the variables such the number of room, kitchens, bathrooms (they are usually low numbers 1 to 5)? wouldn't it cause any problems if the area variables are log transformed?
In some articles they say that the mean and std. dev. standardization is a must for all of the numerical variables. Should I just do it instead of all of the above?

Comment: You are grappling with many important questions, and many of them will no doubt apply to future analyses you conduct.  They seem to require more in-depth and sustained communication than this site provides, though.